# unable to add localhost network to metamask in Ethereum Block Chain

Tags: ethereum, solidity, metamask, ganache

I have no localhost network in metamask and now I want to to add my own localhost network, but it gives me error. Kindly help me in this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with RPC URL: http://localhost:8545/

And of course you have to run the node on your local machine.

Comment: run a node on the local machine, what does that mean?

Comment: maybe the port is blocked on your machine?

Comment: and are you sure your ganache network id is 1337?

Comment: I cannot add a localhost network without running a node on local machine? I didn't get it

Comment: I am not sure if it is 1377, how to confirm?

Comment: how to check if my ganache network id is 1337?

Comment: https://dev.to/dabit3/the-complete-guide-to-full-stack-ethereum-development-3j13
I think this will describe it a little better than I do. The only difference is that you are using ganache and not harthat

Comment: https://dapp-world.com/blogs/01/how-to-connect-ganache-with-metamask-and-deploy-smart-contracts-on-remix-without-1619847868947
I think this is exactly what you are searching for

Comment: @MuhammadAamirKhan  you need to install ganache-cli and run it:  `npm i -g ganache-cli` and then `ganache-cli` and then you can see the port address.